# Свободное место на картинке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Каким образом можно найти пустое место на изображении , для того что бы вставить своё и оно не перекрывали основную ?
Пример картинки (пустое место не постоянно на одном месте)
[image: Вот пример картинки, пустое место не постоянно на одном месте + вместо красного цвета текст]

Код

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vim:fileencoding=utf-8

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, messagebox
import sqlite3
import pyqrcode
import png
import sys
import locale
import fitz



class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
        self.db = db
        self.view_records()

    def init_main(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
# Добавление кнопок управления
        self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='ADD.png') #ADD
        btn_open_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Додати', command=self.open_dialog, bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0,
                                    compound=tk.TOP, image=self.add_img)
        btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.update_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='red.png') #redach
        btn_edit_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Редукувати', bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, image=self.update_img,
                                    compound=tk.TOP, command=self.open_update_dialog)
        btn_edit_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.delete_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='del.png') #Delete
        btn_delete = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Видалити', bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, image=self.delete_img,
                               compound=tk.TOP, command=self.delete_records)
        btn_delete.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.search_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='shearh.png') #Shearh
        btn_search = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Пошук', bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, image=self.search_img,
                               compound=tk.TOP, command=self.open_search_dialog)
        btn_search.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.refresh_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='rel.png') #Obnovit
        btn_refresh = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Обновити', bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, image=self.refresh_img,
                                compound=tk.TOP, command=self.view_records)
        btn_refresh.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=('ID', 'mark', 'name', 'Kol', 'cena', 'polych',  'FIO', 'Adress', 'tel', 'ERDPOU',  'email', 'data', 'shetchik1'), height=15, show='headings')
#Расположение кнопок
        self.tree.column('ID', width=30, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('mark', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('name', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('Kol', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('cena', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('polych', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('FIO', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('Adress', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('tel', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('ERDPOU', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('email', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('data', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('shetchik1', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)


#Подпись кнопок
        self.tree.heading('ID', text='ID')
        self.tree.heading('mark', text='Маркування Стандарту')
        self.tree.heading('name', text='Назва Стандарту')
        self.tree.heading('Kol', text='Кількість сторінок')
        self.tree.heading('cena', text='Цена')
        self.tree.heading('polych', text='ФІО')
        self.tree.heading('FIO', text='Отримувач')
        self.tree.heading('Adress', text='Адреса')
        self.tree.heading('tel', text='Телефон')
        self.tree.heading('ERDPOU', text='ЄРДПОУ')
        self.tree.heading('email', text='Електронна адреса')
        self.tree.heading('data', text='Дата')
        self.tree.heading('shetchik1', text='shetchik1')

        self.tree.pack()
# Функции кнопок
    def records(self, mark, name_standart, kilkiststr, cena, FIO, polych, Adress, tel, ERDPOU, email, data, shetchik1):  #Запись
        self.db.insert_data(mark, name_standart, kilkiststr, cena, FIO, polych, Adress, tel, ERDPOU, email, data, shetchik1)
        self.view_records()

    def update_record(self, mark, name_standart, kilkiststr, cena, FIO, polych, Adress, tel, ERDPOU, email, data, shetchik1): #Обновить
        self.db.c.execute('''UPDATE work SET mark=?, name_standart=?, kilkiststr=?, cena=?, FIO=?, polych=?, Adress=?, tel=?, ERDPOU=?, email=?, data=?, shetchik1=? WHERE ID=?''',
                          (mark, name_standart, kilkiststr, cena, FIO, polych, Adress, tel, ERDPOU, email, data, shetchik1, self.tree.set(self.tree.selection()[0], '#1')))
        self.db.conn.commit()
        self.view_records()

    def view_records(self): #Просмотреть
        self.db.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM work''')
        [self.tree.delete(i) for i in self.tree.get_children()]
        [self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=row) for row in self.db.c.fetchall()]

    def delete_records(self): #Удалить
        for selection_item in self.tree.selection():
            self.db.c.execute('''DELETE FROM work WHERE id=?''', (self.tree.set(selection_item, '#1'),))
        self.db.conn.commit()
        self.view_records()

    def search_records(self, polych):   #Поиск
        polych = ('%' + polych + '%',)
        self.db.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM work WHERE polych LIKE ?''', polych)
        [self.tree.delete(i) for i in self.tree.get_children()]
        [self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=row) for row in self.db.c.fetchall()]


# Открытие окон
    def open_dialog(self):
        Child()

    def open_update_dialog(self):
        Update()

    def open_search_dialog(self):
        Search()


class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_child()
        self.view = app

    def init_child(self):
        self.title('Додати')
        self.geometry('400x620+250+100')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        def get_file_name():
            input_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            output_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
            barcode_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            # определить позицию (верхний правый угол)
            image_rectangle = fitz.Rect(450, 170, 550, 270)
            # retrieve the first page of the PDF
            file_handle = fitz.open(input_file)
            first_page = file_handle[0]
            # добавить изображение
            first_page.insertImage(image_rectangle, filename=barcode_file)
            file_handle.save(output_file)

        def GenerateQR():
            qr2 = (self.entry_name_standart.get() + ' ' + self.entry_mark.get() + ' ' + self.entry_kilkiststr.get() + ' ' + self.entry_polych.get() + ' ' + self.entry_Adress.get() + ' ' + self.entry_tel.get() + ' ' + self.entry_ERDPOU.get() + ' ' + self.entry_email.get() + ' ' +  self.entry_data.get() + ' ' + self.entry_shetchik1.get())


            qr = pyqrcode.create(qr2, encoding='UTF-8')
            qr.png('qrtest', scale = 6)

        self.btn1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Выбрать файл', command=get_file_name)
        self.btn1.place(x=50, y=480)

        self.btn2 = ttk.Button(self, text='QRCode', command=GenerateQR)
        self.btn2.place(x=50, y=520)

        label_mark = tk.Label(self, text='Маркування Стандарту:')
        label_mark.place(x=50, y=50)
        label_name_standart = tk.Label(self, text='Назва Стандарту:')
        label_name_standart.place(x=50, y=80)
        label_kilkiststr = tk.Label(self, text='Кількість сторінок:')
        label_kilkiststr.place(x=50, y=110)
        label_cena = tk.Label(self, text='Цена:')
        label_cena.place(x=50, y=140)
        label_FIO = tk.Label(self, text='ФІО:')
        label_FIO.place(x=50, y=170)
        label_polych = tk.Label(self, text='Отримувач:')
        label_polych.place(x=50, y=200)
        label_Adress = tk.Label(self, text='Адреса:')
        label_Adress.place(x=50, y=230)
        label_tel = tk.Label(self, text='Телефон:')
        label_tel.place(x=50, y=260)
        label_ERDPOU = tk.Label(self, text='ЄРДПОУ:')
        label_ERDPOU.place(x=50, y=290)
        label_email = tk.Label(self, text='Електронна адреса:')
        label_email.place(x=50, y=320)
        label_data = tk.Label(self, text='Дата:')
        label_data.place(x=50, y=350)
        label_shetchik1 = tk.Label(self, text='shetchik1:')
        label_shetchik1.place(x=50, y=380)


        self.entry_kilkiststr = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_kilkiststr.place(x=200, y=50)

        self.entry_name_standart = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_name_standart.place(x=200, y=80)

        self.entry_mark = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_mark.place(x=200, y=110)

        self.entry_cena = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_cena.place(x=200, y=140)

        self.entry_FIO = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_FIO.place(x=200, y=170)

        self.entry_polych = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_polych.place(x=200, y=200)

        self.entry_Adress = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_Adress.place(x=200, y=230)

        self.entry_tel = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_tel.place(x=200, y=260)

        self.entry_ERDPOU = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_ERDPOU.place(x=200, y=290)

        self.entry_email = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_email.place(x=200, y=320)

        self.entry_data = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_data.place(x=200, y=350)

        self.entry_shetchik1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_shetchik1.place(x=200, y=380)


        btn_cancel = ttk.Button(self, text='Закрити', command=self.destroy)
        btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=480)

        self.btn_ok = ttk.Button(self, text='Додати')
        self.btn_ok.place(x=220, y=480)
        self.btn_ok.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.view.records(self.entry_kilkiststr.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_name_standart.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_mark.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_cena.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_FIO.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_polych.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_Adress.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_tel.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_ERDPOU.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_email.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_data.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_shetchik1.get()))





        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()





































class Update(Child):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_edit()
        self.view = app
        self.db = db
        self.default_data()

    def init_edit(self):
        self.title('Редукувати')
        btn_edit = ttk.Button(self, text='Редукувати')
        btn_edit.place(x=205, y=480)
        btn_edit.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.view.update_record(self.entry_kilkiststr.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_name_standart.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_mark.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_cena.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_FIO.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_polych.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_Adress.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_tel.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_ERDPOU.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_email.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_data.get(),
                                                                       self.entry_shetchik1.get()))

        self.btn_ok.destroy()

    def default_data(self):
        self.db.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM work WHERE id=?''',
                          (self.view.tree.set(self.view.tree.selection()[0], '#1'),))
        row = self.db.c.fetchone()
        self.entry_mark.insert(0, row[1])
        if row[2] != 'Доход':
            self.name_standart.current(1)
        self.entry_kilkiststr.insert(0, row[3])



class Search(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_search()
        self.view = app

    def init_search(self):
        self.title('Пошук')
        self.geometry('300x100+400+300')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        label_search = tk.Label(self, text='Пошук')
        label_search.place(x=50, y=20)

        self.entry_search = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_search.place(x=105, y=20, width=150)

        btn_cancel = ttk.Button(self, text='Закрити', command=self.destroy)
        btn_cancel.place(x=185, y=50)

        btn_search = ttk.Button(self, text='Пошук')
        btn_search.place(x=105, y=50)
        btn_search.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.view.search_records(self.entry_search.get()))
        btn_search.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.destroy(), add='+')


class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('work.db')
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute(
            '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS work (id integer primary key, mark text, name_standart text, kilkiststr real,cena integer, FIO text, polych text, Adress text, tel integer, ERDPOU text, email text, data text, shetchik1 integer)''')
        self.conn.commit()

    def insert_data(self, mark, name_standart, kilkiststr, cena, FIO, polych, Adress, tel, ERDPOU, email, data, shetchik1):
        self.c.execute('''INSERT INTO work(mark, name_standart, kilkiststr, cena, FIO, polych, Adress, tel, ERDPOU, email, data, shetchik1) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''',
                       (mark, name_standart, kilkiststr, cena, FIO, polych, Adress, tel, ERDPOU, email, data, shetchik1))
        self.conn.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    db = DB()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.title("Робота")
    root.geometry("1450x450+0+0")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Я хочу pdf файл конвертировать в изображение после чего вставить qr cod на пустое место что бы он не перекрывал текст

Comment: ничего не понятно. Приведите пример вашего кода и объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример изображения с пустым местом и пример того, что Вы в итоге хотите увидеть.

Comment: @S.Nick Добавил код программы + объяснение чего именно хочу

Comment: @nomnoms12 Добавил пример картинки

Comment: Погуглите про библиотеку cv2 скорее всего с её помощью можно решить. Что-то типа findContours

Comment: Пустое место в рамочке или нет? Это важно )

Comment: @CrazyElf без рамочки

Comment: @KoTAK Ясно. А цвет всегда так, что снаружи цветной, а в рамке белый или нет?

Comment: @CrazyElf, нет не всегда , бывает что там и там белый

Comment: @KoTAK В общем, посмотрите функции, которые есть в `cv2`, я навскидку не подскажу что вам больше подойдёт из того, что там есть, но оно наверняка есть

Comment: @KoTAK И примеров изображения тогда нужно больше и конкретных.

Comment: попробуй вырезать кусок - посчитать среднее отклонение цвета в этом квадрате, если меньше незначительного, то лепи код на это место. Если больше - то двигай на 5 пикселей и заново