# Как вставить изображение в PDF что бы оно ничего не перекрывало

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Как вставить картинку в PDF файл что бы он проверял не перекрывает ли картинка текст , расположение пустого места не одинаковое, наполнение PDF то же разное

Вот пример кода но он просто вставляет картинку по координатам

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, messagebox
import sqlite3
import pyqrcode
import png
import sys
import locale
import fitz
input_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
output_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
barcode_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
# определить позицию (верхний правый угол)
image_rectangle = fitz.Rect(450, 170, 550, 270)
# retrieve the first page of the PDF
file_handle = fitz.open(input_file)
first_page = file_handle[0]
# добавить изображение
first_page.insertImage(image_rectangle, filename=barcode_file)
file_handle.save(output_file)
```

Comment: пдф сделал из из картинок https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1158543/Свободное-место-на-картинке ?

Comment: @eri , хочу попробовать двумя методами , поскольку через PDF будет более удобно , а в pymypdf нашел функцию 'fitz.Empty' но не смог с ней разобраться

Comment: вопрос другой был)